# How to migrate a folder from another branch while keeping history in git?

Tags: git

I have a folder `scripts` in the `master` branch that has been changed over **several** commits.

I have a feature branch, `feat-xxx` that does not have that folder.

I want to migrate that folder `scripts` to the `feat-xxx` branch and keep history.

So maybe I want to cherry-pick all commits on the master branch that target that `scripts` folder. How to I do that?

Comment: You can do `git merge` if you don't mind merge commit. Another ways are `git rabase` or `git cherry-pick` as you said.

Comment: What do you mean when you say, migrate to the other branch?

Comment: @Behe replicate that folder on the feature branch while keeping history

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?
Do you want to have only the changes that created and changed the directory in your branch and not some others?